# I am trying to create malayalam pdfs using FPDF. font using meera.ttf It is working but is not working

Tags: php, pdf, unicode, fpdf, truetype

- I am trying to create malayalam pdfs using FPDF.

  Font using **meera.ttf**

  It is working but is not working correctly.

  Result is like this ഇഗലീഷ്

  I want the result ഇംഗ്ലീഷ്

  codes*****

  ```
     $pdf = new tFPDF();
     $pdf->AddPage();
     // Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
     $pdf->AddFont('meera','','meera.ttf',true);
     $pdf->SetFont('meera','',14);
     // Load a UTF-8 string from a file and print it
     $txt = file_get_contents('HelloWorld.txt');
     $pdf->Write(8,$txt);
     // Select a standard font (uses windows-1252)
     $pdf->SetFont('meera','',14);
     $pdf->Ln(10);
     $pdf->Write(5,'The file size of this PDF is only 12 KB.');
     $pdf->Output();
     ?>
  ```

  HelloWorld.txt

  ---

  ഇംഗ്ലീഷ്

Comment: This has nothing to do with **`FPDF`** , you need to make use of some other different malayalam font.

Comment: Agreed;  I've seen that problem with Telugu a lot. Some fonts  do context awareness for characters well and others don't.

Comment: try mpdf. support all langs

Answer (score 1):

i got answer, use mpdf,
fpdf and tcpdf not support.

go to
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#sent/143096e2010c4a58

download ful version of  mPDF v5.7 Full installation - Download (.ZIP file 12.8MB)

run example /example29_multilingual_autofont.php

eg. localhost/MPDF57/examples/example29_multilingual_autofont.php

Comment: Check the link that you give.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution. 
Just Download mpdf 6.0 and use the following Query

```
<?php
include('mpdf.php');
$html = '
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-image:url(image.jpg); background-image-resize:6;} 
footer {page-break-after: always;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p >ഇംഗ്ലീഷ്</p>

<p style="font-family:Courier New">Malayalam</p>
</body>
</html>';
$mpdf=new mPDF('ml');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Thats not an answer, but an alternative.